# callback when finish fs.writeFilesync

Tags: javascript, fs

I have this line of code to create file.I want that after the file is created i got a message like 'file created succefully'.

```
fs.writeFileSync('reports/' +fileName+ '.pdf', resp.content);
```

Comment: The question title is a bit misleading... Synchronous methods like `writeFileSync` do not have a callback... ?

Comment: how can detect that the file is created?

Comment: @Mat The line after `fs.writeFileSync()`

Comment: It's a **synchronous** function. Just write code below it. And read the documentation, it tells you the function returns number of bytes written.

Comment: @Mat Also it returns number of bytes written - so if fewer than expected bytes something went wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you are using is a synchronous method. There is no need for a callback for such merhods. If you want to display message after the operation is done, just console log it in the next line.

```
fs.writeFileSync('reports/' +fileName+ '.pdf',  resp.content);
console.log('write operation done');
```

If you want to write to a file asynchronously then use `fs.writeFile` instead.

```
fs.writeFile('reports/' +fileName+ '.pdf', resp.content, ()=>console.log('write operation done');
);
```